# Validated a number with 2 decimal place and less than 1000

Tags: regex, xml

I know there are many similar question being asked, but i need help on this
and if possible please provide me a easy to follow and easy to understand tutorial for regex.

Here is some valid scenario
999.99 valid 
100.00 valid 
1111.00 invalid
111.002 invalid

the code should be written in this pattern 

but i dont know how to code the output i want

thank you in advance!

Comment: You could start by reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info). What you're asking for is extremely basic, in the likes of `\d{1,3}\.\d{2}`. Try websites like [this one](http://regexr.com/) to learn!

Comment: Actually, you should try a bit yourself. Go to http://regex101.com, and try `\d` pattern with `{1,2}` quantifier (=min.1 max.2 occurrences). Escape the `.` as `\.` to match it literally. Post us what you tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this restriction in an XSD document:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="2dnumber">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
        <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{2}|1000.00"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Or if you just want to use an `xs:decimal` directly:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="2dnumber">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
        <xsd:minExclusive value="0"/>
        <xsd:maxExclusive value="1000"/>
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="2"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `maxEclusive` value be 1000?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like

```
/^((\d{1,3}\.\d{2})|(1000.00))$/
```

`\d{1,3}` between one and three digits

`\.` a decimal

`d{2}` 2 digits after the decimal

`|` or

`1000.00` special case for 1000.00

`^` start of string

`$` end of string

**EDIT**

if you want less than 1000, try this

```
/^((\d{1,3}\.\d{2})$/
```

Comment: This doesn't match `1000.10`.

Comment: 1000.10 is more than 1000

Comment: I think the question includes 1000 with any digits afterwards, but you may be right.

Comment: <1000
so 1000 is not valid

Comment: it says not more than 1000, should reword the question to say less than 1000 then

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match 1.00 to 1000.00 you can use the below:

```
^([1-9]{1,1}[0-9]{0,2}\.[0-9]{2})|(1000\.00)$
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please make sure you use the formatting tools.